# Data streaming with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming

We need to stream large data, which is a large set of points (x, y), how can we implement a streaming of data using actionscript 3?

As we are targeting android using Adobe AIR, would achieving data streaming be possible?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flash.net.Socket or flash.net.XMLSocket to send and receive data in a stream-oriented way.

Comment: Thanks, but how would the server send the data divided into little kbs? for example 50kb each packet?

Comment: Form a packet on a server-side with an appropriate length and just write it in a socket. You can't control network encoding, packet sizes, etc. It will be chosen appropriately by an OS. If you need a "packet bounds" on a flash side, then write packet length then a packet content and on a client read length then wait until all packet data is available (maybe XML socket will handle it for you). If you do not need a guaranteed delivery, you may try to use DatagramSocket. But it is available only in air application and packet size is very limited.

Comment: Can you please see my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921709/action-message-format-vs-downloading-xml-files/15921784?noredirect=1#15921784