# Action Message Format vs downloading XML files?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, amf, zend-amf

As we are about to start downloading big data from the server, we have two options to work with:

1. Downloading compressed XML file each 10 seconds, where we will store data to be consumed at the client site.
2. Calling Zend AMF Server each 10 seconds, and listening to methods callback results, it will return data that we will be consuming at client side. ( inspired by [Zend AMF – AS3 and PHP](http://www.sgermain.net/tutorials/amf-pt1/) )

Which approach will be faster? and which approach will save us bandwidth?
Any recommendation?

Comment: Without any doubt AMF will save your bandwidth. "AMF3 aims for more compression and one of the ways it achieves this is by avoiding string duplication by saving them into an array against which all new string are checked."

Comment: But what if we compress XML files?

Comment: Then you'll need time for compression/decompression, then parsing XML, which could take much time in case of large size. I'd bet on AMF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMF Hands down http://census2.jamesward.com/

Always best to test but I would put my money on AMF

Comment: So, using AMF at a socket is the way to go? using Zend AMF Server?

Comment: Not sure I understand your follow up question exactly "at a socket"?  I've used both BlazeDS (Java AMF) and Zend for PHP->AMF without issue (transfer size and speed was fast, only issues were created by SQL layer due to complexity of queries and database size).  It's always best to test as close to your expected production environment though.

Comment: If data size and speed are the concern rather than human readability then AMF makes more sense.  XML has the fluff of open and close tags, even compressed your better off with a format that is designed for high speed data transmission rather than one designed for human readability. http://www.gotfuturama.com/Multimedia/EpisodeSounds/1ACV05/11.mp3